# How is default new thread name given in java?

Tags: java, multithreading

When I run this program

```
public class Fabric extends Thread {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Fabric());
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Fabric());
        Thread t3 = new Thread(new Fabric());
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();
    }
    public void run() {
        for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        System.out.print(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " ");
    }
}
```

I get output

```
Thread-1 Thread-5 Thread-5 Thread-3 Thread-1 Thread-3
```

Is there any specific reason why the threads are given names with odd numbers - 1, 3, 5... Or is it unpredictable?

Comment: Did you check the documentation?

Comment: Yes, but I may have missed something.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
new Thread(new Fabric());
```

Since `Fabric` is a Thread, you created 2 threads here :)

JDK8 code:

```
/* For autonumbering anonymous threads. */
private static int threadInitNumber;
private static synchronized int nextThreadNum() {
    return threadInitNumber++;
}
```

Comment: Does this mean that everytime the JVM creates a `Thread`, it increments a global counter?

Comment: @ChetanKinger - that would make sense. what else could it do? pick an animal name? :)

Comment: @Chetan Kinger, yes, unless the Thread is given a specific name upon construction.

Comment: Animal names would have been fun.

Comment: @ChetanKinger - see "What is with the really weird link names?" http://gfycat.com/about#links

Comment: @copeg adding to your answer... that global counter which is getting incremented, will not be decremented if we set a custom name... I tried it

Comment: "you created 2 thread *objects* here". The thread itself is not created until `start()` is called, so only one thread is (eventually) created.

Comment: @Andreas - well, it's just wording. Both the Javadoc and JLS implies that "thread" exists before start() and after stop(), as well as during suspension. But of course we usually refer to "thread" as something that is running.

Answer (score 6):

The default numeric value in the Thread name is an incremented value *unless* the name is specified when creating the Thread. `Fabric` extends `Thread`, and you are passing the `Fabric` instance to create another Thread - thus the internal Thread counter is incremented twice as 2 threads are created during the process.

Comment: "as 2 thread *objects* are created". The thread itself is not created until `start()` is called, so only one thread is created.

Comment: @Rookie I was trying to clarify the difference between a `Thread` object and an actually running CPU thread. Both `new Fabric()` and `new Thread()` create `Thread` objects, but `start()` is only called on one of them, so once one of them creates a CPU thread.

Comment: @Andreas It's out of curiosity if I was missing something. Thanks btw.

Answer (score 2):

If you change the program like given below you will get the thread numbering in sequence.

```
    public class Fabric extends Thread {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread t1 = new Fabric();
        Thread t2 = new Fabric();
        Thread t3 = new Fabric();
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();
    }
    public void run() {
        for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            System.out.print(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " ");
    }
}
```

and the output is

```
Thread-0 Thread-2 Thread-2 Thread-1 Thread-0 Thread-1
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, it's just an incrementing counter.

The reason why your log file does not print your thread names in order, is because **java does not guarentee the order of execution of the started threads**.

If you want to force the order, then you have to make the threads wait for eachother. A possible way to do this, is using a `CountDownLatch`.

```
private static CountDownLatch latch;

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Thread t1 = new Thread(new Fabric());
    Thread t2 = new Thread(new Fabric());
    Thread t3 = new Thread(new Fabric());

    // the countdown starts at 1.
    latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    t1.start();
    // the thread will wait till the countdown reaches 0. 
    latch.await();

    latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    t2.start();
    latch.await();

    latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    t3.start();
    latch.await();
}
public void run() {
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
      System.out.print(Thread.currentThread().getName());

  // thread is done: set counter to 0.
  latch.countDown();
}
```

On the other hand, some classes use a `ThreadFactory` to assign thread names. (e.g. a `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`). For example the `DefaultThreadFactory` creates its thread names as follows:

```
String namePrefix = "pool-" + poolNumber.getAndIncrement() + "-thread-";
String threadName = namePrefix + threadNumber.getAndIncrement()
```